# Bootstrap- Navbars menu items not visible when clicking hamburger icon

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I appreciate all the help I can get :)

I'm trying to do a collapsable navbar with Bootstrap 3.3.7 with a hamburger icon on smaller viewports.

I can't get the hamburger icon to work. I've managed to make a hamburger icon which is visible only on smaller viewports but when I click the hamburger icon it doesn't show the menu items that it should contain.

How can I make the hamburger icon work?

Here is the code for the navigation bar:

```
<!-- Navigation bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">   <!-- Creates margins for the navbar content on left and right -->


      <!-- Home icon -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target:"#mainNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
    </div>


     <!--  Menu items  -->
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavbar">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: have u added the **bootstrap js** file ?

Comment: Yes I have. I've copied the basic template from Bootstraps website and there are both jquery and js scripts included.

Comment: If this is your real code replace your typo `data-target:"#mainNavbar"` with `data-target="#mainNavbar"`. Seems to work just fine now.

Comment: Hey that's why it didn't work! Thank you! I missed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet... taken from w3schools... simple and cool.. dont forget to add **bootstrap JS file**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
  </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you! This one worked, I don't know why. I made changes to it and copied it to the original file and it works. This snippet with my changes is the same as my code before but for some reason my old code didn't work and the new one does. So weird!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `bootstrap js` cdn within your `head` tags and making sure you have the latest version of jQuery.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Keep in mind, you need to load the jQuery before loading in Bootstrap.

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hkLfx6u8/16/

Comment: This didn't work for me. And in Bootstrap documentation it says that the scripts should be in the end before the closing body tag.